# need to sum series and get upper bound with parameter from sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

how to show that for $x\in[0,m_0]$ and for all $s$
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}{\frac{1}{(1+(x-nm_0)^2)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{(1+(x-nm_0+s)^2)^{3/2}}}\le\frac{C}{(1+s^2)^{(1+\varepsilon)/2}}$$
where $\varepsilon>0$ and $C$ is some constant ($\varepsilon$ is probably 2)

tried some majorization to deal with $3/2$ but no idea how to get $\frac{1}{1+s^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x\in[0,m_0],\quad n\in\mathbb Z$
$$1+(x-nm_0)^2 \ge 1+ (|n|m_0-x)^2 \ge 1 + (\max(|n|-1,0))^2m_0^2,$$
$$1+(x-nm_0+s)^2 \ge 1+(|nm_0-s|-x)^2 \ge 1+(\max(|nm_0-s|-m_0, 0))^2,$$
so
$$S = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}{\frac{1}{(1+(x-nm_0)^2)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{(1+(x-nm_0+s)^2)^{3/2}}}$$
$$\le \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}{\frac{1}{(1 + (\max(|n|-1,0))^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{(1+(\max(|nm_0-s|-m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}}}$$
$$= \sum_{n = -\infty}^{-1}{\frac{1}{(1 + (n+1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{(1+(\max(|nm_0-s|-m_0, 0))^2))^{3/2}}}$$
$$+ \frac{1}{(1+(\max(|s|-m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{(1 + (n-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{(1+(\max(|nm_0-s|-m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}}}$$
$$= \frac{1}{(1+(\max(|s|-m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + (-n+1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(\max(|-nm_0-s| - m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + (n-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(\max(|nm_0 - s| - m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$= \frac{1}{(1+(\max(|s|-m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + (n-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(\max(|nm_0+|s|| - m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + (n-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(\max(|nm_0 - |s|| - m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$= \frac{2}{(1+(\max(|s|-m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(1+|s|^2)^{3/2}} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(nm_0+|s|)^2)^{3/2}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(\max(|(n+1)m_0 - |s|| - m_0, 0))^2)^{3/2}}.$$

If $\underline{|s|\in[0, m_0]},$ then
$$S \le 2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(n-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$\le 3 + \frac{1}{(1 + m_0^2)^{3/2}}  + {1\over m_0^6}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^6} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^3(n+1)^3}\right)$$
$$\le 3 + {1\over(1 + m_0^2)^{3/2}} + {1.14774\over m_0^6}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%7B1%5Cover+n%5E6%7D+%2B+%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%7B1%5Cover+n%5E3(n%2B1)%5E3%7D)).

If $\underline{|s|\in[m_0, 2m_0]},$ then
$$S \le {8\over1+m_0^2} + \frac{1}{(1 + m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(n+1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(1 + m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(1 + 4m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(n-2)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$\le {10\over(1 + m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(1 + 4m_0^2)^{3/2}} + {1\over m_0^6}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^6} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over n^3(n+2)^3}\right)$$
$$\le {10\over(1 + m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(1 + 4m_0^2)^{3/2}}
 + {1.05674\over m_0^6} \le {10\over(1 + m_0^2)^{3/2}}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%7B1%5Cover%20n%5E6%7D%20%2B%20%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%7B1%5Cover%20n%5E3(n%2B2)%5E3%7D))

If $\underline{|s|\in[km_0,(k+1)m_0],\quad k\ge 2},$ then
$$S = \frac{1}{(1+|s|^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{2}{(1+(k-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(n+k)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} 
+ \sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(k-n-2)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(1 + (k-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}$$
$$ + \frac{1}{(1 + (k+1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \sum_{n=k+2}^\infty\frac{1}{(1 + n^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+(n-k-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} 
$$
$$\le \frac{1}{(1+|s|^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{3}{(1+(k-1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(1+(k+1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} + {1\over m_0^6k^3}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3} 
+ \sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n^3} + \sum_{n=k+2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}\right) 
$$
$$\le \frac{1}{(1+|s|^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{12}{(1+k^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(1+(k+1)^2m_0^2)^{3/2}} + {2\pi^2\over 6m_0^6k^3} - {1\over m_0^6k^6} - {1\over m_0^6k^3(k+1)^3} \le (14+{\pi^2\over3}){(1+s^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}$$

After combining the results:
$$\boxed{S \le \frac{17.3}{(1+s^2m_0^2)^{3/2}}.}$$

Comment: thanks for the answer but the bound can't have +1 in it because it will be summed over $s=Ck$ over $k$ ant that sum needs to converge. here is the paper I was reading. it is best to see the source, maybe I didn't formulate question correctly. T2.5 page 18-19 in pdf the part when it is says that conditions are satisfied if $|g(x)|\le C(1+x^2)^{-3/2}$ . here is the link. https://services.math.duke.edu/~ingrid/publications/ieee36-1990.pdf

Comment: it could be that I need that bound for all $s$ except on some finite interval. I thought it was easier. maybe I should post better formulated question?

Comment: @jack Fixed, thanks.